# MIPS check if user input is in an array

Tags: assembly, mips

Is there a way that I can check if a user input is in a given array? Like if I had an array of [1,3,5,7,9] and the user entered 1, I would want to return 1. If not, is there an alternative to doing multiple comparisons without using beq 5 times?

Comment: How about you use a loop.

Comment: If you can use a real MIPS CPU that supports SIMD extensions (https://www.mips.com/products/architectures/ase/simd/), you can compare 4x 32-bit elements in parallel.  If this is for MARS/SPIM, then use a loop if you don't want to fully-unroll